# 'clean all target' is not available

Tags: iphone

I hope to activate 'clean all targets' to rebuild and change the display of my app.
But 'clean all target' still is not available.
Is there a way to renable 'clean all target'?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcut keys is `Shift+Command+K` to clean the target. Another hand `Product->Clean` to clean the target. I hope it will help you a bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you hold down the option key while the Product menu is open it will change "Clean" to "Clean Build Folder".